# Why does Excel 2013 ignore my keystrokes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, microsoft-office

I was doing some copying and pasting into this new Excel file, and all of a sudden the keyboard is not being recognized in Excel.

I am also unable to save this file. Anyone have ideas?

Here is a GIF of the application in its failed state:

[image: GIF of the application in its failed state]

Comment: The only workaround for me was to end-task Excel.exe and hope that the file was auto-saved.

Comment: Weird, that acts almost as if there is a modal window open, maybe hidden, except that you can still interact with fields and menus.  That or maybe the machine and/or app thinks a shift/alt/ctrl key is stuck

Comment: Is this limited to Excel? Or do other Office applications also have the same issue? Still happen after reboot? You may want to conduct a repair installation to fix any corrupt files.

Comment: Yes it was Excel only. Word, Powerpoint were just fine. The Shift/Alt/Control keys were not stuck, tried to show that with the On Screen Keyboard trying to force some kind of input.

Comment: 1) Did you download the Excel spreadsheet? 2) Was it is read-only mode? 3) Are you able to double-click inside a cell to accept data?

Comment: Nope, in the title screen of the Excel window it shows that it was a new spreadsheet. It shouldnt have been in read-only mode. I was not able to double click a cell to accept data.

Comment: Not sure what the fix was, but if you attempt a print to a printer, the interface begins to respond again.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I went to another instance of Excel that I had running, played around in there, and went back to my "problem" application, the keyboard (and mouse's scroll wheel) started working again.  Otherwise, I couldn't do much, and I couldn't save the file.